# How to solve IDX21323: RequireNonce is '[PII is hidden]'?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, adfs

I've got a WebApplication running on .NET 5 and using `OpenidConnect` authentication having ADFS 4 as the Identity Server.

I'm getting the `IDX21323: RequireNonce is 'True'. OpenIdConnectProtocolValidationContext.Nonce was null, OpenIdConnectProtocol.ValidatedIdToken.Payload.Nonce was not null. The nonce cannot be validated. If you don't need to check the nonce, set OpenIdConnectProtocolValidator.RequireNonce to 'false'. Note if a 'nonce' is found it will be evaluated.` error in some browsers(tested Chrome,Edge,Opera), but `NOT` in `firefox`. In Firefox the authentication flow goes as expected.

Any idea why this might be happening?

My guess is that for some reason, all the tested browsers besides firefox, remove the `Nonce` cookie.

Comment: Set `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true` to see the omitted info.